# I have a question about Python Classes & Events

Tags: python, oop, events

My understanding of python is limited. In a different forum, someone asked about classes. In my explanation, I said Classes contain 3 things: properties, methods, and events. While several agreed with my comment, one person said I was wrong, that python classes do not contain events. So my question is simple. Do/can python classes contain events?

thank for taking the time to set me straight.

Comment: In Python use the term attributes or maybe data members. Reserve the use of the `property` term for when you implement a real property, usually with the decorator syntax @property

Answer (score 2):

Python classes have methods and properties.

Events can be implemented in Python using the Observer pattern.

This blog has a nice example of implementing events in Python.
https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/observer/python/1